# C++ SFML Animation System

Tags: c++, game, animation, sfml

I'm attempting to write an animation system on top of SFML, and I've come up with a design where I can wrap sf::Drawable objects into a RenderComponent class, and the RenderComponent class can be given an Animation object at any time, which will overwrite a previous animation if one exists. Here is what I'm looking for.

1. Am I using the std::unique_ptr correctly/optimally?
2. Should I be using a pointer to store the Animation?
3. Is my method of settings the animation (with a variadic template) too complicated, and is there a better way?
4. I would normally separate the code into header and implementation, but for the brevity, I am uploading it in pure headers. Ignore that please.
5. Any general advice.

**Here is the code:**

Animation base class

```cpp
class Animation {
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock hrc;

private:

    std::chrono::time_point<hrc> m_now;

protected:

    unsigned int m_us;      // us for microseconds
    unsigned int m_endUs;

    void UpdateTime() {
        auto end = hrc::now();
        auto diff = end - m_now;
        m_now = end;
        auto msDuration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(diff);
        m_us += (unsigned int)msDuration.count();
    }

public:

    Animation() {
        m_us = 0;
        m_now = hrc::now();
    }

    bool finished() {
        return m_endUs <= m_us;
    }

    virtual bool Update(sf::Sprite& spr) = 0;

};
```

Animation child class

```cpp
class FadeIn : public Animation {

public:

    FadeIn(int ms) {
        m_endUs = ms * 1000;
    }

    // Updates the sprite based on the timeline, and returns if the animation is over
    virtual bool Update(sf::Sprite& spr) {
        UpdateTime();
        if (finished()) return true;

        sf::Color color = spr.getColor();
        color.a = (int)((float)m_us / m_endUs * 255);
        spr.setColor(color);
        return false;
    }

};
```

Render Component

```cpp
class RenderComponent {

private:

    sf::Texture m_texDefault;
    std::unique_ptr<Animation> m_animationPtr;

public:

    RenderComponent() { }
    RenderComponent(sf::Drawable* element, sf::Vector2u size) {
        sf::RenderTexture rt;
        rt.create((unsigned int)size.x, (unsigned int)size.y);
        rt.draw(*element);
        m_texDefault = rt.getTexture();
    }

    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    void SetAnimation(Args... args) {
        m_animationPtr = std::make_unique<T>(args...);
    }

    void draw(sf::RenderTarget* target) {
        sf::Sprite sprite;
        sprite.setTexture(m_texDefault);

        // Handle animation and set pointer to null if done
        if (m_animationPtr) {
            if (m_animationPtr.get()->Update(sprite)) {
                m_animationPtr = nullptr;
            }
            sf::Color c = sprite.getColor();
        }
        target->draw(sprite);
    }

};
```

A helper function

```cpp
sf::Vector2u floatRectToVec2u(sf::FloatRect r) {
    sf::Vector2u vec;
    vec.x = (unsigned int)ceil(r.width);
    vec.y = (unsigned int)ceil(r.height);
    return vec;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}
```

Main function

```cpp
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    RenderComponent circle(&shape, floatRectToVec2u(shape.getGlobalBounds()));
    circle.SetAnimation<FadeIn>(1000);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        circle.draw(&window);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (Too late, but) Welcome to Code Review!  Nice first question.

Answer (score 2):

## Animation base class

> ```
> typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock hrc;
> ```

In modern C++, use an *alias-declaration*:

```
using hrc = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
```

It is arguably more readable.

> ```
> std::chrono::time_point<hrc> m_now;
>
> unsigned int m_us;      // us for microseconds
> unsigned int m_endUs;
> ```

The types and names of the last two members are not helpful.  (By the way, `unsigned int` = `unsigned`.)  And they should be `private`:

```
private:
    using time_point = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point;
    time_point m_now;

    using duration = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration;
    duration m_time_elapsed;
    duration m_total_time;
```

The derived classes should have read-only access to `m_total_time`:

```
protected:
    auto total_time() const
    {
        return m_total_time; 
    }
```

> ```
> void UpdateTime() {
>     auto end = hrc::now();
>     auto diff = end - m_now;
>     m_now = end;
>     auto msDuration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(diff);
>     m_us += (unsigned int)msDuration.count();
> }
> ```

This function is a bit complex because of the conversion between different types.  They can be simplified:

```
void UpdateTime()
{
    auto time = hrc::now();
    time_elapsed += time - m_now;
    m_now = time;
}
```

> ```
> Animation() {
>     m_us = 0;
>     m_now = hrc::now();
> }
> ```

The constructor should provide a means to set the `m_total_time` member.  And it should use member initializer clauses instead of assignment:

```
template <class Rep, class Period>
explicit Animation(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& total_time)
    : m_now{hrc::now()}
    , m_time_elapsed{}
    , m_total_time{total_time} // std::chrono::duration supports conversion
{
}
```

(The support for different `duration`s is for convenience.)

> ```
> bool finished() {
>     return m_endUs <= m_us;
> }
> ```

You are missing `const`.

> ```
> virtual bool Update(sf::Sprite& spr) = 0;
> ```

Good.

## Animation child class

> ```
> FadeIn(int ms) {
>     m_endUs = ms * 1000;
> }
> ```

Missing `explicit` — an integer is not logically a `FadeIn`.  Type mismatch (you are using `unsigned` in the base class).  With the design mentioned, just do this:

```
using Animation::Animation;
```

And the constructors will work as expected.

> ```
> // Updates the sprite based on the timeline, and returns if the animation is over
> virtual bool Update(sf::Sprite& spr) {
>     UpdateTime();
>     if (finished()) return true;
>
>     sf::Color color = spr.getColor();
>     color.a = (int)((float)m_us / m_endUs * 255);
>     spr.setColor(color);
>     return false;
> }
> ```

Missing `override`.  Don't use C-style casts.  `float` may be too imprecise for this calculation.  Don't put the whole `if` statement on a single line.

The color algorithm should be in a separate function:

```
private:
    sf::Color get_color() const noexcept
    {
        auto color = spr.getColor();

        double ratio = static_cast<double>(m_time_elapsed) / m_total_time;
        color.a = static_cast<int>(ratio * 255);
        return color;
    }
```

Also, if overflow is not a concern, just multiply first and then divide to avoid the floating point.  And then the function can be simplified:

```
virtual bool Update(sf::Sprite& spr) override
{
    UpdateTime();

    if (finished()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        spr.setColor(get_color());
        return false;
    }
}
```

## Render Component

> ```
> RenderComponent() { }
> RenderComponent(sf::Drawable* element, sf::Vector2u size) {
>     sf::RenderTexture rt;
>     rt.create((unsigned int)size.x, (unsigned int)size.y);
>     rt.draw(*element);
>     m_texDefault = rt.getTexture();
> }
> ```

Good — except for the C-style casts:

- remove them if possible;
- otherwise, use `unsigned{size.x}` if possible;
- otherwise, use `static_cast`.

> ```
> template <typename T, typename... Args>
> void SetAnimation(Args... args) {
>     m_animationPtr = std::make_unique<T>(args...);
> }
> ```

You are missing perfect forwarding:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void SetAnimation(Args&&... args)
{
    m_animationPtr = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

> ```
> void draw(sf::RenderTarget* target) {
>     sf::Sprite sprite;
>     sprite.setTexture(m_texDefault);
>
>     // Handle animation and set pointer to null if done
>     if (m_animationPtr) {
>         if (m_animationPtr.get()->Update(sprite)) {
>             m_animationPtr = nullptr;
>         }
>         sf::Color c = sprite.getColor();
>     }
>     target->draw(sprite);
> }
> ```

Always turn warnings on — unused `c` variable should issue a warning.  (I am pretty sure `sprite.getColor()` has any side effects.)

## A helper function

> ```
> sf::Vector2u floatRectToVec2u(sf::FloatRect r) {
>     sf::Vector2u vec;
>     vec.x = (unsigned int)ceil(r.width);
>     vec.y = (unsigned int)ceil(r.height);
>     return vec;
>     auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
> }
> ```

This function is a pure math function, so should probably be `noexcept`.  The name is a bit awkward — it does not mention `ceil` at all.  Also, it seems that `ceil` should be `std::ceil`.  And what does the last line do?

If `sf::Vector2u` can be constructed with the coordinates, the code is simplified:

```
sf::Vector2u ceil_vector(sf::FloatRect r)
{
    return {std::ceil(r.width), std::ceil(r.height)};
}
```

## Main function

> ```
> int main()
> {
>     sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
>     sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
>     shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
>     RenderComponent circle(&shape, floatRectToVec2u(shape.getGlobalBounds()));
>     circle.SetAnimation<FadeIn>(1000);
>
>     while (window.isOpen())
>     {
>         sf::Event event;
>         while (window.pollEvent(event))
>         {
>             if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
>                 window.close();
>         }
>
>         window.clear();
>         circle.draw(&window);
>         window.display();
>     }
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

The main function looks nice.  (I don't why you are explicitly specifying `100.f` here instead of `100`, but maybe there's a good reason.)  `return 0;` is redundant for `main` and can be omitted.  `event` can be declared in the inner loop with `for`.